# Is it okay to let a range view own a shared_ptr containing state it needs?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Basically I am trying to get around the fact that the following does not work with range-v3 ranges: (this is a toy example but illustrates the problem.)

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto bad_foo() {
    std::vector<int> local_vector = { 23, 45, 182, 3, 5, 16, 1 };
    return local_vector |
        rv::transform([](int n) {return 2 * n; });
}

int main() {

    for (int n :bad_foo()) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The above doesn't work because we are returning a view that references data that will go out of scope when `bad_foo` returns.

What I want to do is store the vector in a shared pointer in such a way that the range view will keep the shared pointer alive. Note that the obvious version of this idea does not work i.e.

```
auto still_bad_foo() {
    auto shared_vector = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(
        std::initializer_list{ 23, 45, 182, 3, 5, 16, 1 }
    );
    return *shared_vector |
        rv::transform([](int n) {return 2 * n; });
}
```

still fails because `shared_vector` is not actually getting captured by the range view. What we want to do is force the range view to own the shared pointer.

The following seems to work to me.

```
auto good_foo() {
    auto shared_vector = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>(
        std::initializer_list{ 23, 45, 182, 3, 5, 16, 1 }
    );
    return rv::single(shared_vector) |
        rv::transform([](auto ptr) {  return rv::all(*ptr); }) |
        rv::join |
        rv::transform([](int n) {return 2 * n; });
}
```

We use `single` to turn the shared pointer into a single item range view, turn the single item into a range of ints by dereferencing the pointer in `transform` and wrapping the vector in a range with `all`, yielding a composition of range views, which we then flatten via `join`.

My question is is the above really safe and if so is there a less verbose version of the same idea?

Edit: updated the question to just be about range-v3 ranges as @康桓瑋 has alerted me that this issue is not a problem with C++20 ranges as long as it is not a requirement for the owning range views to be copyable.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, if you want to pass ownership of a vector's contents to the caller, why not just return the vector itself? You could do the transformations directly on the vector elements and then return a concrete collection, rather than hacking together weak pointers to data that's about to go out of scope.

Comment: this is a toy example. the real code involves much more deeply generated views. it's for a procedural art application ive been doing for fun. So far these views have not needed to own state but I want to add some features where I see no way around it. To stop using range views for all this would entail a rewrite. the actual code is here: https://github.com/jwezorek/crosshatching

Answer (score 2):

> Basically I am trying to get around the fact that the following does
> not work: (this is a toy example but illustrates the problem. I'm
> using range-v3 but this question applies to standard ranges too)

If you are using the standard `<ranges>` then you don't have to worry about this, just move the `vector` into the pipe, which will move the ownership of the `vector` into [`owning_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/owning_view)

```
auto not_bad_foo() {
  std::vector<int> local_vector = { 23, 45, 182, 3, 5, 16, 1 };
  return std::move(local_vector) | // <- here
    std::views::transform([](int n) {return 2 * n; });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/57WKeW4nj)

Comment: i didn't know this ... 
so standard ranges will become owning ranges any time a vector is piped from? isn't that going to make the view require O(n) to copy though? I thought views were supposed to take only O(1) to copy?

Comment: @jwezorek `owning_view` is a *move-only* view, which still meets the requirements of the `view` concept, you can refer to the original paper [P2415](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2415r2.html).

Comment: Is P2415 part of C++20 or is it a C++23 feature? 
I'm currently using range-v3 so I'd have to convert everything over and I do use some things like zip that arent in C++20.

Comment: @jwezorek It's C++20 DR, so it's a C++20 feature.

Answer (score 1):

How about capturing the vector in a lambda to extend its lifetime?

```
auto create_foo() {
    std::vector<int> local_vector = { 23, 45, 182, 3, 5, 16, 1 };
    return [captured_vector = std::move(local_vector)]() {
        return captured_vector | rv::transform([](int n) {return 2 * n; });
    };
}

int main() {
    for (int n : create_foo()()) {
        std::cout << n << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: i need it to be a view not a lambda